# What's the maximum rate for growing lollipops?

Tags: candy-box

I read somewhere that you can't grow more than 100 lollipops a second.  Is this true?  If so, how many lollipops do I have to plant in order to get 100 a second?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get up to 300 lollipop/sec with the **horn** item, which multiplies by 3 your Lp production.

To get to 100/sec, it is something around 17.5k Lp planted. You will know when you get there.

Answer (score 10):

After you beat the final boss, you unlock the ability to create "bugs" in the game using the Developper's Computer (that is not a typo). However, these bugs cost millions of lollipops to use. This is no issue at this point in the game. One of the so called bugs removes the 100 (300 with horn) cap. So if you invested beyond the 17,401 lollipops into your farm, it'll produce more, up to 10,000 lollipops per second. However, at this point in the game, this is just for laughs as the so called "bugs" can be used to gain 1,000's of trillions of lollipops and candies. (This particular bug costs 10 million lollipops)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the legitimate way to get 100 lp/s you can do that, but it will take some time;

One you've managed to plant around 17,000 Lollipops in your farm, you'll achieve 100 Lp/s.

You can increase your maximum Lp/s by getting the **Horn O' Plenty** by killing the Cow King on the Cow level. But that's a looooong way away.

Once you've unlocked the Developpers Computer, you can "hack" more unlocks getting up to 10,000 Lp/s. With 30,000 Lp/s via the Horn o' Plenty.

If you're looking to get a certain amount, there's a much easier way through javascript;

Open the Developer Tools (Right click, select Inspect Element)
Go to Console.
Type in the following.

`lollipops.nbrOwned=X;`

X being the amount you want, and you'll see it will instantly change your set amount of lollipops to X

If you're looking to set your candies per second, that's easy too;

`candies.nbrOwned=X;`

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: That doesn't changed candies per second, but rather the total number of candies.

Answer (score 0):

During most of the game, the limit is 100 lp/s, but with the bugs from the Developper's Computer, the limit can be raised to 10,000 lp/s. The Horn of Plenty multiplies all lollipop production by three, so the highest effective lollipop growth rate is 30,000 lollipops per second.

Comment: So I now have the horn, but I'm not getting 300lp/s.  what else do I have to do?

Comment: The increase from the horn doesn't display in the farm, but you *are* getting the 300 per second.

Comment: No, no I'm not.  My count only goes up by 100 each second.

Comment: I suspect you have the wrong horn. What you have is "A magical horn", right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I still get the other one from unicorns, right?

Comment: No, if you keep using GMOOH potions, you'll eventually get the other one.

Comment: @MBraedley the horn of plenty comes from defeating the cow king on the cow level. You get to the cow level by using the GMOOH (Get me out of here) potion. There is a one in four chance in reaching the cow level with the potion. Other locations it will teleport you to are the peaceful forest, the sea, and the desert.